# PS Help to KeyDown and Click with functions and hash tables

Tags: function, powershell, listbox, click, addition

I have something like this:

```
#initialize System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms
#$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form , $form.text, $form.Size etc
#$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox , $listBox.Location etc

$form.KeyPreview = $True

$form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){ 
#call func passing $item value to the currentItemSelected parameter of func
$item=$listBox.SelectedItem;(Func -currentItemSelected $item)}}) 

$form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})

$hashT1 = Get-Content -raw "path\hashT.txt" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$hashT2 = Get-Content -raw "path\hashT2.txt" | ConvertFrom-StringData

#arg is recieved from Btn.Add_Click(), btn1 clicked arg1 = $hashT1, btn2 = $hashT2 ...
function PopList($arg1){
$listBox.Items.Clear()
foreach ($game in $arg1.GetEnumerator() | sort Name){
$listBox.Items.Add("{0}" -f $game.Key)}

##Function recieve $hashT1 or any table I state when I click a Button
##and recieve the listbox.SelectedItem value when I press enter
##Write-Host is just to check if the variables recieved the correct info
function Func($currentHashT, $currentItemSelected ){
Write-Host $currentHashT.$currentItemSelected}

$btn1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
#{.location, .size, .text...}
#PopList fill list with $hashT1 keys and Func $currentHashT should be $hashT1 'cause I'm
#passing $hashT1 as argument
$btn1.Add_Click({PopList $hashT1; Func -currentHashT $hashT1})
$form.Controls.Add($bt1)

$btn2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
#{.location, .size, .text...}
#PopList fill list with $hashT2 keys and Func $currentHashT should be $hashT2 'cause I'm
#passing $hashT2 as argument
$btn2.Add_Click({PopList $hashT2; Func -currentHashT $hashT2})
$form.Controls.Add($btn2)

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```

As a result I want to click a button, fill my list, select item and when press enter and it write-host me the VALUE of the KEY that I stated I want to.
So if I click btn1, select an item from the list and press Enter it will write-host the VALUE of $hashT1.'KEY' e.g:
$hashT1 = @{"File 1" = "Path\File1.bin"; "File 2" = "Path\File2.cue"}
clicked btn1, filled list box with 2 lines, "File 1" and "File 2".
select any of them, File 2 for now.
pressed enter, it will write-host: Path\File2.cue

What I am getting as result:
"blank line" followed by Selected item value

If I write my Func to Write-Host $currentHashT.'File 2' it DOES work
If I write my Func to Write-Host $hashT1.$currentItemSelected it DOES work
But if I do this way, I'll have to make a function for every button I want to add, can I do this the way I want? Using variables that change according to what I want...
Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the variables change values, the problem is that you're trying to call a function with two parameters like

```
function add ($a, $b) {
    write-host ($a + $b)
}

add -a 4

add -b 5
```

and expecting that to somehow only call the function once, and print 9. That's never going to work.

You could do it by keeping the `$currentHashT` in the parent scope, and the function just references that instead of having it passed in by a parameter:

```
function add($b) {
    write-host ($firstNUm + $b)
}

$n = 4
$firstNUm = $n
add -b 5

$n = 5
$firstNUm = $n
add -b 5
```

Otherwise you'd have to completely redesign it.

Comment: Yea I realized it yesterday and already redesigned to a much less noob script hah, ty.